# Suspense and lazy load a modal in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui, lazy-loading

I'm applying `<Suspense />` and `lazy()` to optimize my project. So far everything works fine, but I've noticed a small changes in the way DOM is handled and it leads me some confusion about the way I'm working on.

Let's assuming this scenario in a CMS/dashboard context. When user visits `/products/`, react-router will handle this `<ProductPage />` container, fetching the component and load it onto the page.

In this `<ProductPage />` container, there's an datatable showing a list of products, and a Add button to add new product. Clicking this `Add buton` will trigger `<Modal />` to show the form.

```
// products.js

class ProductsPage extends React.Components {
   ...
   render() {
      <Grid>
         <AddButton />
         <ProductsDatatable />
         { this.state.isShowingAddingProductForm && (
            <AddModal />
         )}
      </Grid>
   }
}
```

I'm using all of those components (datatable, button and modal) from Material-UI for this project.

**CONCERNS**

1. I'm `lazyLoading` the `<AddModal />`, the `addModal.chunk.js` file will be imported once user clicks on the `<AddButton />` the first time. The tradeoff here is the animation from M-UI. Once I close the Modal, the DOM will be removed from the page hence there will be no animation on form closing. Though this is just a small fade animation.
2. If I remove the `this.state.isShowingAddingProductForm`, the animation will be back. But here I find the network also loads `addModal.chunk.js` even when the user doesn't want to add a new product. Think outside a bit and you know there might be 4 or 5 other modals working on the same logic.

**QUESTIONS**: what's the best approach in working with this Modal scenario? I still want to keep both lazy import and small built-in animation from Material-UI.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Make this:

```
    // products.js

class ProductsPage extends React.Components {
   ...
   render() {
      <Grid>
         <AddButton />
         <ProductsDatatable />
         <AddModal open={this.state.isShowingAddingProductForm}/>
      </Grid>
   }
}
```

And in AddModal component use prop `open` and pass it to MUI modal

Your Modal doesn't have animation on close, because your state `isShowingAddingProductForm` changed to false and AddModal removes from DOM.

And it's doesn't depends on lazy loads

If you need REST calls then modal is open, use `componendDidMount` life cycle method in AddModal component

Comment: actually in my project I'm doing exactly your approach, but it turns out the chunk file will be loaded once the `<ProductPage />` is mounted